# Spyder wtih conda environment

Tags: spyder

I am on windows and have spyder installed via anaconda. I open the spyder application and I had previously set it to run with an environment separate from base. It always says the environment at the bottom: `conda: myenv (Python 3.10.0)`. But after updating, I get:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

showing in my IPython console. I searched for a solution but they are all different and some of the commands seem outdated, asking for install specific versions from 3 or 4 years ago. Tried upgrading my conda and all but no luck. It works in the `base` environment..

Comment: The error suggests it cannot find the path of myenv. You say "after updating" - what did you update? Do you have a version of `spyder-kernels` installed in `myenv` that is compatible with the Spyder version installed? Also try to reset Spyder settings (Tools > Reset Spyder to factory defaults).

Comment: There was a suggestion to update spyder when I opened it, so ran the command. It was a conda update spyder, and also to update conda I think (sorry, can't remember exactly). I have `spyder-kernels==2.3.3`. I have just seen that if I close the console (which restarts it), then it works, although it still prints the error message, so seems like something is broken.

Comment: And what version of Spyder? Does Spyder work with the base Anaconda environment? Did you try to reset Spyder settings? If it does not work with the base environment (with everything updated, check again) after resetting settings then I would guess the install (i.e. Anaconda base environment) is broken. At that point you could try to reinstall Spyder (remove then install again), reinstall Anaconda or install Spyder with the windows installer instead. With the latter option you don't have to worry about broken Spyder install envs.